# getAllNetworks устарел

Tags: java, android

Я пишу под 6 android  (подскажите что можно сделать по быстрому  чтобы работало начиная с 6 андроида)

Ругается что устарел

```
предупреждение: [устаревшее] getAllNetworks() в ConnectivityManager устарело
            Network[] allNetworks = ConnectivityMgr.getAllNetworks(); // добавлено в API 21 (Lollipop)
```

.

```
    public class ConnectionDetector {

    public static boolean isNetworkConnected;
    private Context context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        isNetworkConnected = false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Network[] allNetworks = connectivityMgr.getAllNetworks(); // added in API 21 (Lollipop)

        for (Network network : allNetworks) {
            NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = connectivityMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
            if (networkCapabilities != null) {
                if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                        || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                        || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET))
                    isNetworkConnected = true;
            }
        }
        return isNetworkConnected;
    }}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242384/android-getallnetworkinfo-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative

Comment: там все уже устарело

Comment: а зачем это нужно? если показывать статус, то не узнать когда коннект появился. а если чтоб перед сетевым вызовом, то сейчас есть коннект, через секунду нет, и то, что есть wifi, например, не гарантирует доступа в инет...

Answer (score 0):

Работает  с //api >23
(но пока работает) они там уже придумали что-то новое и скоро будет опять БОЛЬ

```
 public class ConnectionDetector {
    
        public static boolean isNetworkConnected;
        private Context context;
    
        public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
    
        public boolean isConnected(){
            
            //api >23
            
            isNetworkConnected = false;
            
                final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    
                if (cm != null) {
                  
                        final Network n = cm.getActiveNetwork();
    
                        if (n != null) {
                            final NetworkCapabilities nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(n);
    
                            return (nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || nc.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI));
                        }
                    }
    
    
            return isNetworkConnected;
            
        }}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ага конечно....